# Class v. Prototype Property

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

[CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript) walks through this example:

```
class Tribble
   constructor: ->
     @isAlive = true
     Tribble.count++

   # Prototype properties
   breed: -> new Tribble if @isAlive
   die: ->
     Tribble.count-- 
     if @isAlive
       @isAlive = false

  # Class-level properties
  @count: 0
  @makeTrouble: -> console.log ('Trouble!' for i in [1..@count]).join(' ')
```

What's the difference between a `class-level` property and a `Prototype` one?

Answer (score 2):

Class-level properties exist one per class object, not separately on each instance.

So, in your example, there would be only one variable `count` accessible to all your instances rather than a separate member variable for each instantiated object.

Other languages would call these class-level items "static" properties or methods.

Class-level properties or methods can be used directly without actually having an instance of that type of object because they are specific only to the class, not to a specific object instantiation of that class.  Prototype methods can only be called on an actual instantiated object.